# How to handle this "session failed to write file" error in PHP?

Tags: php, session, error-handling, kohana, kohana-3

I am using the Kohana 3 framework, and am using the native session driver.

For some reason, occasionally the sessions fail to write to their file.

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_*****, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/site/public_html/system/classes/kohana/session/native.php  on line 27
```

I am pretty sure Kohana has its own in built error handler, but it is not triggered with this error (i.e. it shows up like a normal PHP error, not the Kohana error).

[image: PHP error]
<sub>(source: [alexanderdickson.com](http://alexanderdickson.com/hosted/stackoverflow.com/php-session-error.png))</sub>

Anyone that has ever used Kohana will notice this seems to have bypassed Kohana's error handling (perhaps set with [`set_error_handler()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)).

Is there anyway to stop this error from appearing *without* switching from the native session (i.e. file based) driver?

Should I just give good practice the boot and prepend an `@` error suppressor to `session_start()` in the core code of Kohana? Should I relax the `error_reporting()`?

Thanks

Comment: I have this problem sometimes using my normal session handling as well. Sometimes the session files just randomly lose permissions and have to be erased. I don't know why it happens.

Comment: don't suppress errors, please :)

Comment: @animuson I know, it's the weirdest thing! It happens *very* occasionally, but I'd rather it not happen at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call `ini_set('session.save_path', APPPATH.'sessions')` (replace `APPPATH.'sessions'` with the directory you want) in bootstrap.php to force sessions to be written to `application/sessions`. This will increase the security of using native sessions and *should* solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to php's session.save_path directive, you can override it to some writable folder in php.ini, or you can try this in your .htaccess;

```
 php_value session.save_path '/path/to/folder/you/can/write'
```

Edit: just so I don't forget, put your custom session folder level below the htdocs/public_html/whatever.

Although, all this is a little overkill since you can ask your server admin politely to check what's the problem with permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This means your php interpreter has no write permissions in /tmp.
Ask your server administrator to fix that - it's unrelated to your app.

In case there are collisions with session files from different php processes (running under different users): Giving them different session temp dirs would help.
For example, you could move them away from /tmp to /path/to/homedir/phptmp and use a structure like that:

```
/path/to/homedir/
/path/to/homedir/htdocs
/path/to/homedir/phptmp
/path/to/homedir/logs
```

Comment: See my second part of the answer ;)